# What's the best-practises liveness check for Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1

I have an HTTP healthcheck endpoint that checks that infrastructure dependencies such as Cassandra is up and running. For SQL databases liveness is commonly checked by executing `SELECT 1`. Is there an equivalent query that can be executed against Cassandra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could query for the cassandra version

```
SELECT release_version FROM system.local
```

Comment: Assume such will tell you if you could reach your connected coordinator node plus the needed read consistency level replicate(s) of this piece of data only. It would/should not replace monitoring of the hole distributed cluster/ring state ImHO.